# Webform Event Registration Match Contact

Tags: civievent, drupal, webform-civicrm, duplicate-contacts

I have created a webform (Drupal) for people to register for an event. I am trying to avoid creating duplicate individuals if they already exist in Civi when they register, but at the moment whenever there is a registration it always creates a new contact, even if they already exist.

When setting up the webform, in the Civi settings I selected Existing Contact, but kept the Existing Contact component hidden and set to static. I have included First Name, Last Name and Email fields. For the Matching Rule under the contact fields, I have set this to a custom unsupervised rule that just does a check on first name and last name. However, even with all these settings, it is still creating a new contact every time for the event.

Am I misunderstanding the way event registrations work? I want to avoid getting existing contacts to login to Drupal before registering if possible, as I want to keep the form as simple as possible. Would it make a difference if I used a profile form instead?

If I cannot solve this then I guess I can always merge contacts afterwards, but it would be nice if duplicates weren't created in the first place.

I'm using Civi 5.9.0 with Drupal 7.61.

I'm attaching a couple of screenshots of my settings:

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

Images for the rules settings and the Name Only rule:

[image]

[image]

Comment: your matching rule says "name only", maybe you should go back and test this rule in civicrm. Try adding an existing contact as new contact in CiviCRM with this rule and check if it works. There is also a similar discussion on this topic here https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/can-drupal-webform-integration-update-matching-contacts

Comment: maybe add screenshot of that matching rule too

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the matching rule. As I understood it if I maually add an existing contact I would need to change the rule type to Supervised? I did click on the "Use" rule and it was certainly picking up everyone with the same first name and last name.